# Asp.net core 3.1 options pattern does not call my delegate

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to follow the options pattern as described [on microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-3.1) and [here](https://andrewlock.net/delaying-strongly-typed-options-configuration-using-postconfigure-in-asp-net-core/).

Here is where I register the action used to configure my options

```
public static class MyServiceCollectionExtensions
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddMyService(this IServiceCollection services, Action<MyOptions> setupAction)
    {
        //Add services required for using options
        services.AddOptions();

        //Add services for our options
        services.AddSingleton<IMyOptions, MyOptions>();

        services.Configure<MyOptions>(setupAction);

        return services;
    }
}
```

And here is where I set this up in startup.  The MVC options delegate fires, but my delegate does not, and I just can't seem to figure out why.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMyService(options =>
    {
        ...
    });
    services.AddMvc(options =>
    {
        ...
    })
}
```

Comment: Are you resolving an instance of e.g. `IOptions<MyOptions>` anywhere?

Comment: @Kirk Larkin, how do I do that?

Comment: I think you're mixing concepts. The `AddSingleton` you have will create a brand new `MyOptions` when requested, but that instance won't be affected by the following `Configure` call. Drop your `AddSingleton` and resolve `IOptions<MyOptions>` from DI - that's the options pattern, which I guess is what you want.

Comment: Perhaps I am mixing concepts.  I'm trying to implement a similar pattern used in the AddMvc approach (which I thought was called the options pattern).  The AddMVC exension method calll services.Configure(Action<TOption>) which accepts a delegate, which is then invoked later. This way, options can be determined in the application via a callback, not in the library itself.

Comment: Yeah, that sounds right. Those delegates will only run once you request `IOptions<MyOptions>` from the DI container. My original question was just around whether you are doing that. From your description, I wondered if you were requesting `MyOptions` directly, which wouldn't work. So by "mixing concepts", I mean you might be setting up the options pattern, but not consuming it.

Comment: Can I consume it any way other than through a constructor?

Comment: Just any of the usual DI style approaches. Constructor injection is the most common.